# Azure B2C - Restrict access for default domain after creating custom domain

Tags: azure

I have created an Azure B2C and we have a few user flows. These user flows use the default domain of `b2cinstance.b2clogin.com`. This domain doesn't go through a WAF so I decided to create an Azure Front Door with WAF Policy to set up a custom domain for my Azure B2C instance.

I have set this all up and it is working as expected. We now have the domain `login.mywebsite.com`, which forwards to origin `b2cinstance.b2clogin.com`. for our user flows which is working as expected and can see the requests in the Azure Front Door.

My question if I try to use the domain `b2cinstance.b2clogin.com`, the user flow still works. How do I restrict use of this domain

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in place a custom Azure B2C policy to block access to the original domain

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#optional-block-access-to-the-default-domain-name